# Decrypting manually Android 4.4.2 partitions pulled from phone (SM-G313HN)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, encryption, disk-encryption

Way how I got to this point is that my phone somehow had restarted in my pocket and was asking for password which I entered but upon entering password it restarted so I was basically stuck in bootloop. So I went into adb through recovery and pulled all partitions of the phone so they are on my pc right now. The question is how can I decrypt them. I tried looking around how is 4.4.2 encrypted but didnt find any good answer. I only understood that key is stored in footer of it which I did find there but then arises question of how you derive the encryption key from it? I'm so confused. Also how is sdcard encrypted as I looked at files from sd card they seem to be file-based encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I got more info about how Samsungs encryption works from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUFl2tkyVyo) and was able to decrypt my userdata partition with tool called [Sandy](https://github.com/donctl/sandy). As for SD card I just pulled out eds_p_sd file from /efs partition from my dd dump and put it back into factory reset phone and it worked like a charm. But SD card decryption can also be achieved with the Sandy framework you just need to have eds_p_sd file and right ECryptFS version so the keys work otherwise you will run into problems.